# if use WAL-G, What is happend with old wal files when delete old full backup?

Tags: postgresql, backup, wal

I use WAL-G for backup PostgreSQL.

But i dont know: What is happend with old wal files when delete old full backup.

I drew picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old WAL files will delete wneh delete old full bakup

```
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476029    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000017.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476037    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000018.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476045    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000019.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476055    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001A.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476064    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001B.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476071    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001C.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476081    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001D.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476089    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001E.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476097    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001F.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476105    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000020.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476113    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000021.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476121    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000022.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476131    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000023.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476138    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000024.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476146    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000025.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476154    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000026.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476164    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000027.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476172    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000028.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476180    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000029.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476190    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002A.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476198    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002B.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476205    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002C.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476213    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002D.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476221    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002E.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476229    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002F.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476238    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000030.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476246    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000031.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522402    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000D8/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522421    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000DA_D_0000000C00000001000000D8/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522437    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000DC_D_0000000C00000001000000DA/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522448    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000002000000A0_D_0000000C00000001000000DC/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522457    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000005000000D0_D_0000000C00000002000000A0/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522468    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C000000080000009B_D_0000000C00000005000000D0/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522478    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000000C00000085_D_0000000C000000080000009B/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522488    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000000F0000000D_D_0000000E0000000C00000085/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522500    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001200000074/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522510    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E000000150000007B_D_0000000E0000001200000074/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522520    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E00000018000000BF_D_0000000E000000150000007B/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522530    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001B00000089_D_0000000E00000018000000BF/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522540    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001E00000003_D_0000000E0000001B00000089/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476020    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000016.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476029    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000017.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476037    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000018.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476045    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000019.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476055    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001A.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476064    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001B.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476071    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001C.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476081    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001D.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476089    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001E.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476097    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000001F.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476105    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000020.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476113    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000021.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476121    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000022.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476131    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000023.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476138    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000024.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476146    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000025.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476154    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000026.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476164    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000027.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476172    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000028.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476180    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000029.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476190    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002A.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476198    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002B.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476205    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002C.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476213    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002D.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476221    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002E.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476229    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A0000002F.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476238    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000030.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.476246    will be deleted: wal_005/0000000E0000002A00000031.br
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522402    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000D8/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522421    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000DA_D_0000000C00000001000000D8/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522437    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000001000000DC_D_0000000C00000001000000DA/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522448    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000002000000A0_D_0000000C00000001000000DC/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522457    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C00000005000000D0_D_0000000C00000002000000A0/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522468    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000C000000080000009B_D_0000000C00000005000000D0/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522478    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000000C00000085_D_0000000C000000080000009B/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522488    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000000F0000000D_D_0000000E0000000C00000085/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522500    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001200000074/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522510    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E000000150000007B_D_0000000E0000001200000074/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522520    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E00000018000000BF_D_0000000E000000150000007B/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522530    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001B00000089_D_0000000E00000018000000BF/metadata.json
INFO: 2020/06/15 07:29:03.522540    will be deleted: basebackups_005/base_0000000E0000001E00000003_D_0000000E0000001B00000089/metadata.json
```